# Are variable length arrays an extension in Clang too?

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand that VLAs are not part of C++11 and I have seen this slip by GCC. It is part of the reason I switched to Clang.  But now I am seeing it Clang too.  I am using clang 3.2 (one behind the latest) and I am compiling with
*-pedantic and -std=c++11*

I expect my test to NOT compile yet it compiles and runs.

```
int myArray[ func_returning_random_int_definitely_not_constexpr( ) ];
```

Is this a compiler bug or an I missing something?

In response to the comment here is the random_int_function()

```
#include <random>
int random_int_function(int i) 
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,100);

    int random_int = distribution(generator);  

    return i + random_int;
}
```

Comment: What is "random" int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, variable length arrays are supported in clang 3.2/3.3 contrary to
the C++11 Standard (§ 8.3.4/1).

So as you say, a program such as:

```
#include <random>

int random_int_function(int i) 
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,100);

    int random_int = distribution(generator);  

    return i + random_int;
}

int main() {
    int myArray[ random_int_function( 0 ) ];
    (void)myArray;
    return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs. However, with the options `-pedantic; -std=c++11` that
you say you passed, clang 3.2/3,3 diagnoses:

> warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla]

The behaviour matches that of gcc (4.7.2/4.8.1), which warns more emphatically:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘myArray’ [-Wvla]

To make the diagnostic be an error, for either compiler, pass `-Werror=vla`.

Comment: `-pedantic-errors` may be more useful for making it an error: it makes everything an error that's triggered by `-pedantic`, not just VLAs.

Comment: Thanks Mike and hvd!  I had been assuming that "-pedantic" triggered errors, not just warnings. Both "-Werror" and "-pedantic-errors" do what I want and are great to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Use these options:

1. `-Wvla` to warning vla uses
2. `-Werror=vla` to consider vla an error.

This works in both the clang and gcc compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply plugging the snippets you posted into IDEone, without putting the array declaration into a function, I [get](http://ideone.com/kLGFFJ)

> prog.cpp:12:39: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

Adding a `main()` function around it results in [success](http://ideone.com/Spqcuh), as you observed.

Since C++11 doesn't allow for array declarations that are legal in `main` but not namespace scope, and that is a property of VLAs, it is reasonable to conclude that is what you are seeing.

Update: courtesy Coliru.org, the message from Clang is

> main.cpp:12:9: error: variable length array declaration not allowed at file scope

So that's fairly definite.