# C++ Expression must have constant value

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void sort(int n, T a[]){
       for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
          for(j=i;j<n;j++){
               if(a[i] > a[j]){
               temp=a[i];
               a[i]=a[j];
               a[j]=temp;
               }
           }
     }
}


void main(){
    int size;
    cout<<" Please input the amount of numbers you would like to sort"<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    int Amta[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout<<"Please enter the "<<size+1<< "number";
        cin>>Amta[i];
    }
    Sleep(100000);
}
```

I am trying to get the how many numbers the user would like to input from the user and store it in the variable size.

But when I initialize `array Amta[size]` I get the following compile errors:

> > Expression must have constant value

and

> > C2057: expected constant expression" compile error.

Comment: You should look into the `new` and `delete` operators for making arrays on-the-fly. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/

Comment: Better yet, look into `std::vector` and don't aim around your feet with a loaded gun. Also, `void main` is not legal C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ array - expresssion must have a constant value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219712/c-array-expresssion-must-have-a-constant-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do compilers treat variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627235/how-do-compilers-treat-variable-length-arrays)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't enter a non-constant value between the brackets when you declare your array:

```
int Amta[size];
```

Since you're getting `size` from the user, the compiler can't tell ahead of time how much memory it needs for `Amta`.  The easiest thing to do here (especially for an exercise) is to just choose a relatively large value and make that the constant allocation, like:

```
int Amta[1024];
```

And then if you want to be careful (and you should) you can check `if (size > 1024)` and print an error if the user wants a size that's beyond the pre-allocated bounds.

If you want to get fancy, you can define `Amta` with no pre-set size, like `int *Amta;` and then you allocate it later with `malloc`:

```
Amta = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

Then you must also free `Amta` later, when you're done with it:

```
free(Amta);
```

Comment: `malloc` in C++ is generally a terrible idea.

Comment: @chris: He wants an array of `ints`.  It's not like there's a constructor to be called.  What's the problem?

Comment: @AaronGolden Are your saying if you (personally) were writing  code that required side-by-side independent array allocations of trivially  constructible objects *and* a similar array of integers, you'd use `new` for the objects and `malloc()` for the `int`s? What fun that must be.

Comment: Why bother having to think about what to use based on what type you're allocating memory for? I use a `std::vector` by default. As a bonus, I don't have to clean up.

Comment: Thanks went ahead and used a larger size then i would need and simply used the user input to break out of the loop when they have finished entering the final number.

Comment: in C++ you should use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`

Answer (score 4):

[C++ doesn't allow variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/995714). The size must be a constant. C99 does support it so if you need you can use a C99 compliant compiler. Some compilers like [GCC and Clang also support VLA as an extension in C++ mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17645496/995714)

But if C++ is a must then you can use [`alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) (or [`_alloca` on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019)) to allocate memory on stack and mimic the C99 variable length array behavior

```
Amta = (int *)alloca(sizeof(int) * size);
```

This way you don't need to free the memory after going out of scope because the stackframe will automatically be restored. However [you need to be very careful while using this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1018853/995714). It's still better to use `std::vector` in C++ for these purposes