# a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object c++

Tags: c++

When creating a multidimensional array im getting the following error:

```
a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object c++
```

My code:

```
class Level
{
private:
    int width = 6;
    int height = 6;
    Room rooms[width][height];
public:
    Level();
    ~Level();
};
```

When width and height are replaced, when creating the array, with 6 (the value of the int's) it works. Why can't I use an int that holds the same value?

I don't need variable sizes (else I should use a vector), I thought using some variables would make it more readable for others when reading it.

In my constructor im going to fill the array in a for loop like:

```
Level::Level(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < levelWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < levelHeight; x++)
        {
          //Do the filling here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in C++.

Comment: Maybe you intended `static const int width = 6;`.  Otherwise, `width` is not an int that holds that value.  `width` is a member of `Level` whose default initialization would be that value.

Comment: C-style array dimensions must be constant expressions. Use C++-style arrays if the dimensions may be different

Comment: @101010 You can't do this in any other language either. This is trying to tie the size of a two-dimensional array to two variables.

Comment: @dascandy you can do it in C nowadays.

Comment: @dascandy also in java it's fine, im pretty sure in c# too. I tried this code http://pastebin.com/i2YdW9tT in java.

Comment: @SvenB why not make use of std::array? See my last edit.

Comment: @LBesancon I want to understand why it's not working what I intend so that i understand what is happening. In other language i always did it like that so i would really like to know why it's not working in c++

Comment: @SvenB Hope my new answer will help :)

Comment: @101010 Not as part of a class - in part due to C not having classes. Same goes for java and C# for class members. Only thing you can do is dynamically allocate it at object creation time - but then again, you can do that in C++ as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not allowed in c++. You cannot create variable size array.

If you want to have a variable size I suggest allocating your memory in the constructor according to width and height and declare room as `Room** rooms`;

If you really need variable length, you could also use `std::vector`
In your case you would have: `std::vector<std::vector<Room>> rooms`

---

Edit: 
If you don't need variable length, in that case you need to make `width` and `height` static members or you could use std::array which explicitly made for fixed-sized arrays.

---

Edit2:

Reason why what you are trying to do is not working is because VLA were not implemented in C++ (they are in C though) because if you have a variable size you can simply use the `std::vector`. You can find some discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c++/K_4lgA1JYeg) on that topic.

Also it would appear that what you want to achieve is ok if you use clang (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645496/are-variable-length-arrays-an-extension-in-clang-too)) even though it is contrary to the standards.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the use of raw pointers or `malloc` in C++.

Comment: Well that's one way of achieving it. But you're right, this is not really recommended for C++. Edit on the way

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`? i.e. `std::vector<std::vector<Room>> rooms`

Comment: @EdHeal see my edit (I guess it was committed just a few seconds before you sent the comment)

Comment: @LBesancon I don't need variable length thats why i want to use an array.

Comment: @SvenB to answer the fact that you want to understand why it's not working in C++ see my last edit. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to C++11 you can use `constexpr` values

```
class Level
{
private:
    static constexpr int width = 6;
    static constexpr int height = 6;
    Room rooms[width][height];
public:
    Level();
    ~Level();
};
```

Please note that both member are now static.
Constexpr means that the value can be evaluated at compile time, so it's not a variable size array.

If you want variable sized array you must use vector or (not recommended) use your own memory allocation strategy.

`const` works, but `constexpr` are better. `constexpr` Says that the value can be evaluated at compile time, even with more complex types. You can even make them function, like

```
static constexpr int width() { return 6; }
```

And more importantly, you can use the values inside template parameters.

```
std::array<std::array<Room, width>, height>
```

If you can, I suggess you to read about [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), because they provide a zero overhead alternative to raw arrays

Comment: Why constexpr and not const. const seems to work to.

Comment: there is [no difference between `const` and `constexpr` for `const`literal types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14117121/678093)

Comment: if the type of the value changes, like `Vector2i` to contain `x` and `y`, `constexpr` will be required anyway.

Comment: There is absolutely no garanties about the fact that it will be evaluated at compile time. You can further refer to some posts that were made on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const. So no difference between them for this at least

Comment: garaties that not __will__ be evaluated at compile time, but __can__ be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot you just wrote: "constexpr garanties that the value can be evaluated at compile time". Which is not true at all

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot When using const i can use the value of levelWidth in my constructor, when using constexpr i can't. I want to use these values in my levelWidth to fill the array in a for loop. (i could use length but i was trying with the ints that have the size).

Comment: @LBesancon then I really don't know what `constexpr` means if it don't mean that the expression must be valid to use at compile time. in a constant expression context, you can't do something that cannot be known at compile time, so it indeed garanties that it __can__ be evaluated at compile time. However, the expression can also be evaluated at runtime, but still need to be valid at compile time.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you meant in your initial answer. I thought you meant that constexpr are necessarily evaluated at compile time. My bad if I misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

if you need to provide dimension length you should define it as `static const` or in c++11 `static contexpr` or perhaps pass those argument as template parameters like this

```
template<std::size_t Width, std::size_t Height>
class Level
{
private:
    Room rooms[Width][Height];
public:
    Level();
    ~Level();
};
```

or even better use `std::array`

and if the dimension length not need you may use `std::vector`